# Any example for CarPlay and Android auto using the here Flutter navigate SDK

Tags: here-api

Any example for CarPlay and Android auto using the here Flutter navigate SDK
Do I need to load the SDK on IOS and Android as well on top of Flutter?

Comment: No, currently there is no example for CarPlay and Android Auto platform. May I ask about what is purpose of the SDK on Carplay and Android Auto? These platforms are for Car Head Unit Display purpose. And is it commercial or evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

See this [guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/dev_guide/topics/maps.html#add-support-for-carplay-and-android-auto) for more information. Basically, Flutter itself does not offer support for this. You can try to workaround this limitation using native code examples. See the link.

The native SDKs for iOS and Android are already included as part of the Flutter plugin folder for the HERE SDK for Flutter.